# Pygame and Classes

Tags: python, pygame, subclass

So I'm making a tkinter/pygame game in classes and python doesn't recognise pygame when it is in a class.
(don't worry about how i'm going to start up the windows separately, that will be done once the window works

```
from tkinter import *
from pygame import *
class firstscreen:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.minsize(300, 250)
        self.window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.window.title("Login")
        self.username = ""
        self.password = ""
        self.userlabel = Label(self.window, text="Username")
        self.userlabel.place(x=50, y=50)
        self.passlabel = Label(self.window, text="Password")
        self.passlabel.place(x=50, y=100)
        self.userentry = Entry(self.window, textvariable=self.username)
        self.userentry.place(x=110, y=50)
        self.passentry = Entry(self.window, textvariable=self.password, show="*")
        self.passentry.place(x=110, y=100)
        self.loginbutton = Button(self.window, text="Login", command = self.login())
        self.loginbutton.place(x=80, y=140)
        self.registerbutton = Button(self.window, text="Register",command=self.login())
        self.registerbutton.place(x=140, y=140)
        self.window.mainloop()
    def login(self):
        print("Hello")

class gamewindow():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        game = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 300))
runlogin = firstscreen()
rungame = gamewindow()
```

> ```
> NameError:name 'pygame' is not defined
> ```

(For line 29, pygame.init() )

Comment: Are you getting a specific error of some kind? Please update the question with this information.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, make sure pygame is well downloaded

Comment: @quamrana  name pygame is not defined (on the line of pygame.init() )

Comment: I don't see the text of this error in your question. Have you updated the question yet?

Comment: @quamrana it was in my reply, but i've updated the question now

Comment: @Rabbid76 i need to check it first, but its most likely the answer so i'll temporarily mark it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be either

```py
from pygame import *

# [...]

class gamewindow():
    def __init__(self):
        init()
        game = display.set_mode((800, 300))
```

or

```py
import pygame

# [...]

class gamewindow():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        game = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 300))
```

See [The import system - Submodules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules)